# In Europa Universalis IV, how does 'nationalism' work?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I cannot convert the culture of some of my provinces, due to `You cannot convert the culture of a province that has nationalism`.

However, I've noticed that after some time, nationalism tends to disappear.

I cannot find anything on this topic on the internet, so...

- Which provinces have nationalism (is it hardcoded)?
- Can I tell whether a province has nationalism before conquering it?
- How long do provinces stay nationalist?
- How to tell when the nationalism will expire?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Nationalism**

Nationalism is a modifier that applies to all conquered provinces once conquered.

**What does it do?**

In Europa Universalis IV, every province in your country has a "most likely" rebel type if the *revolt risk* in the province is above 0, you can see what type by hovering the mouse over the *revolt risk* window and reading the tool-tip.

These rebel factions will surface at a percentage chance per month according to their *revolt risk*.

Once conquered a province gets +14.00 *revolt risk* from Nationalism.

**How long does this last?**

Nationalism last for 10 years after being conquered, as the tool-tip states

**What happens?**

Well, apart from giving an increased *revolt risk* by virtue of being affected by nationalism. Not much, it just makes it increasing likely that you will suffer the spawning of a nationalist rebel stack/army.

**Is this bad or good?**

Well, rebels are annoying, Nationalist rebels have a few specific goals, and they can achieve those by successfully negotiating demands from their overlords when they control at least one province.

Nationalist rebels scoring a victory by their overlord negotiating therefore confers the following penalties and benefits titled *local autonomy*:

**Province modifier**:

- *local autonomy* (in all occupied provinces for 20 years)

  - -100% manpower
  - -100% tax
  - -100% tariffs
  - -100% production
  - -50% missionary strength

**However**
The one advantage of allowing the rebels to succeed in their war goal, at least to the point of negotiation is that you gain

- -10 revolt risk

to the province, which *may* help you maintain order in your empire if at a particularly low stability or prestige/weak geo-political standpoint.

If you let them enforce their demands however, by letting the war-score tick over and not dealing with the irritating rebellion, you will find yourself acquiescing to the nationalistic rebel's demands, which has the following effect:

- Rebel nation released

Comment: Interestingly, that particular province (Kola, while playing as Norway) had religious rebels, not nationalist. For some reason, I don't see a nationalism tooltip. Do I need all the DLC for that?

Comment: This I would suggest is that the leading rebel faction, ie: the highest % of rebelliousness-ness, is religious,... which is over 14(minus any nationalistic rebel modifiers, from national perks etc)%... does the tool-tip say religious zealots 14.01% ?

Comment: ie: Just because nationalism exists, does not make it automatically the highest % revolt group

Comment: The game deigns to inform you as coring a province that has nationalism is not allowed, you must wait for it to expire

Comment: Hover your mouse over the _revolt risk_ for the rebel tool tip info, you didn't get a 'nationalism' in province modifier row, this would be because different things may have occurred in the new game, if in your previous game, although you didn't actually see the rebellion, it is likely the previous owner (before you conquered it) did, and lost, hence the rebels being able to enforce their demands.

Comment: This answer should be updated for the new unrest system

Comment: Unrest/nationalism still works the same (though it's called Separatism now instead of nationalism), it's just a lot less random, since revolts build slowly over time based on how much support that faction has in your country from provinces with revolt risk that support them. They're also a lot easier to deal with before they even become a threat (provided you've not messed up somewhere and let them get out of control), but are also a lot stronger if you do allow them to fire compared to the old completely random revolts.